# teamcity not calling postbuildevent in msbuild project

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, post-build-event

I have defined the postbuildevent in project which is working fine locally but when called from Teamcity it is not calling the following event:-

```
<PropertyGroup>
<PostBuildEvent>xcopy /Y /E "$(TargetDir)\Shared\Scripts" "$(ProjectDir)\Shared\Scripts"</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
```

I tried passing via command line parameters in msbuild configuration of teamcity but that is also not working

```
/M /P:Configuration=%system.Configuration% /P:PostBuildEvent="xcopy /Y /E "$(TargetDir1)\Shared\Scripts" "$(ProjectDir1)\Shared\Scripts""
```

Please guide.

Comment: Could you try creating a new target with a &lt;Copy /&gt; task, and include a &lt;Message /&gt; task with high importance to confirm it is firing?

Comment: I thought xcopy required files as the source parameter?